# When should I start and destroy session in PHP

Tags: php, session, oauth

I am making a simple oauth site.

In `index.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['authentication']))
    $_SESSION['authentication'] = 'pending';
?>
<html>
<form action="oauth.php" method="post">
    <span>
    <?php
        echo $_SESSION['authentication'];
    ?>
    </span>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="authenticate">
    <input type="submit" value="authenticate">
</form>
</html>
```

In `oauth.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'authenticate') {
    $url = $serverAuth ... ;
    header('Location: ' . $url); //google oauth, it will come back to oauth.php
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $ch = curl_init($serverToken);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $tokens = json_decode($result, true);

    if (isset($tokens['access_token'])) {
        $_SESSION['authentication'] = 'good';
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $tokens['access_token'];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['authentication'] = 'error';
    }

    header('Location: ./');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    if ($_GET['error'] == 'access_denied')
        $_SESSION['authentication'] = 'denied';
    else
        $_SESSION['authentication'] = 'error';
    header('Location: ./');
    exit();    
}
?>
```

I want to make the site like: by default, `$_SESSION['authentication']` is "pending"; when I refresh the page, every session variables are gone, and `$_SESSION['authentication']` reset to default. But I cannot reset `$_SESSION` at the beginning of `index.php`, because functions in `oauth.php` have `header()` to redirect to this page.

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start the session on **every single page that requires access to `$_SESSION`**. Only destroy it when explicitly requested, e.g. on logout.

Comment: What does refresh have to do with it?